# ¿Cóma mantener estático un modal encima de un slider fullscreen usando Materialize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3, materialize

Estoy usando Materialize y quisiera que encima del slide fullscreen poner un botón que abre un modal y dentro de éste colocar un formulario de registro de información o llenado de datos para luego poder cerrarlo mientras las pantallas del slide en el fondo no dejan de fluir.

Comment: Si suministras el código de ejemplo será mas fácil que usuarios de aquí se interesen en ayudarte a solucionar el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sería mucho mejor con un código que tengas. Lo poco que logro entender es que el modal se sobre ponga a todo, hasta el slide fullscreen.

Se puede sobreponer con la propiedad [z-index de css](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

> Mientrás más grande sea el valor de z-index más al frente estará de la pantalla. Inclusive soporta valores negativos.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.modal').modal();
      $('.carousel').carousel();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  
   <!-- Modal Lanzador -->
  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>

  <!-- Modal Estrucutura -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal" style="z-index: 10;">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
   <div class="carousel">
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5"></a>
  </div>
```